# Golang OData Request via net/http package

Tags: http, go, odata

I am trying to send request to a test OData server. I tried to most of endpoints in this https://www.postman.com/collections/bf7d9130241aaa7160d8 collection. However some of endpoints return error when I sent request with net/http package. Probably the reason is about endpoint string spaces. What is the correct way to send request to this endpoint with golang.

my code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People?$filter=FirstName eq 'Vincent'")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalln(resp.Status)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    sb := string(body)
    fmt.Println(sb)
}
```

Returns "400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `url` package's `Values` and `Encode` method from `net/url` package.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    baseURL := "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People"

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("$filter", "FirstName eq 'Vincent'") 

    requestURL := baseURL + "?" + v.Encode() // put it all together
    resp, err := http.Get(requestURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalln(resp.Status)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    sb := string(body)
    fmt.Println(sb)
}
```

Resources:

[Values type](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Values)

[Values.Encode example](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#example-Values.Encode)

Comment: It returns error : Get "http%3A%2F%2Fservices.odata.org%2FV4%2FTripPinService%2FPeople%3F%24filter%3DFirstName+eq+%27Vincent%27": unsupported protocol scheme "

Comment: @oakkose I've updated the answer. I've tested it and it returns response.